# Unable to access answers.unity.com

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, forum

I am currently facing this issue where accessing any links from Google that leads to answers.unity.com tends to redirect me to this page where it says 'Your license has expired.'

[image]

Things that I've tried:

1. Different links from Google, each leading to different threads
2. Clearing cookies, history, open in incognito
3. Tried clicking on the profile icon on the top right corner next to the search icon, which does nothing.

I had not contacted the sales@answerhub.com as mentioned in the description of the status. I thought that it might be a technical issue and was wondering if anyone faced the same issue or have a fix for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am also facing this issue as well. Glad to see I'm not the only one.

Comment: This is not a question about programmation, and even if it might be helpful right now (as you're clearly not the only one to face this outage), I think this question doesn't belong on StackOverflow, nor will have lasting value in a few days. Voting to close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unity's License of [AnswersHub](https://www.answerhub.com/), the back-end that supports the answers.unity.com has expired. This has nothing to do with your personal/enterprise license of Unity or your Unity account.
Once Unity renews their License of AnswersHub, we will be able to access it again.

EDIT:
[Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/index.html) is **live** again.

Comment: I see! Thanks for answering! This was getting very frustrating and it also helps me realize how dependent I am on the stackoverflow of unity xD

Comment: @Kayton almost everyone that was on answers is now on StackOverflow .. Answers was kinda abandoned a while ago .. there is almost no moderation anymore ;)

Comment: its donw again for the same reason:D